# Knowledge Base Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I'm after a Knowledge Base Sharepoint 2010.Anyone built something similar or is there anything free i can use.Looking for any related resources.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

There is a Knowledge base template as part of the Fantastic 40 for SharePoint 2007.

> The Knowledge Base application
>   template helps teams manage the
>   information that is resident within
>   their organization. The template
>   enables team members to upload
>   existing documents or create new ones
>   using Web-based content creation
>   tools. Items are tagged with relevant
>   identifying information so that others
>   can more easily find the documents and
>   learn from the collective knowledge in
>   their organization. The template can
>   be utilized in a 'top down' approach,
>   where a centralized knowledge
>   department 'pushes down' relevant
>   content to the rest of the business or
>   a 'bottom up' approach, where
>   knowledge is captured and shared by
>   all users as a normal part of doing
>   business.

[Here](http://marijnsomers.blogspot.com/2010/06/fantastic-40-templates-on-sharepoint.html) is a guide to get them working on SP2010 (havent tested it though).

Grab it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5807b5ef-57a1-47cb-8666-78c1363f127d&displaylang=en)

Or see them in action [here](http://www.wssdemo.com/application/default.aspx)